# Ignore padding class (0) during multi class classification

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, nlp, tensorflow2.0

I have a problem where given a set of tokens, predict another token. For this task I use an embedding layer with `Vocab-size + 1` as `input_size`. The `+1` is because the sequences are padded with zeros. Eg. given a `Vocab-size` of 10 000 and `max_sequence_len=6`, `x_train` looks like:

```
array([[    0,     0,     0,    11,    22,     4],
       [    29,     6,     12,    29,  1576,    29],
       ...,
       [    0,     0,     67,    8947,  7274,  7019],
       [    0,     0,     0,    15,  10000,    50]])
```

`y_train` consists of integers between 1 and 10000, with other words, this becomes a multi-class classification problem with 10000 classes.

**My problem**: When I specify the output size in the output layer, I would like to specify 10000, but the model will predict the classes 0-9999 if I do this. Another approach is to set output size to 10001, but then the model can predict the 0-class (padding), which is unwanted.

Since `y_train` is mapped from 1 to 10000, I could remap it to 0-9999, but since they share mapping with the input, this seems like an unnecessary workaround.

EDIT:
I realize, and which @Andrey pointed out in the comments, that I could allow for 10001 classes, and simply add padding to the vocabulary, although I am never interested in the network predicting `0`'s.

How can I tell the model to predict on the labels 1-10000, whilst at the meantime have 10000 classes, not 10001?

Comment: I usually set vocab_size to 10001 and I've never seen that the model predicted 0

Comment: In reality, my vocab_size is way larger, and I use the top-k probabilities in my use-case, so it actually happens (very rarely), that 0 is part of the top-k predictions :(

Comment: I would add padding symbol to the end of vocab and fix output shape as 10000 (not len(vocab) = 10001)

Comment: Or I would add padding as additional input (instead of using a special vocab symbol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the following approach:

```
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=())
x = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(10001, 512)(inputs) # input shape of full vocab size [10001]
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10000, activation='softmax')(x) # training weights based on reduced vocab size [10000]
z = tf.zeros(tf.shape(x)[:-1])[..., tf.newaxis]
x = tf.concat([z, x], axis=-1) # add constant zero on the first position (to avoid predicting 0)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)

inputs = tf.random.uniform([10, 10], 0, 10001, dtype=tf.int32) 
labels = tf.random.uniform([10, 10], 0, 10001, dtype=tf.int32)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(inputs, labels)

pred = model.predict(inputs) # all zero positions filled by 0 (which is minimum value)
```

Comment: I appreciate the continuous effort, and this could be the best possible solution, although I would hope for one where the modification is with the keras model, and not with the data. This is because, if I save the model for later use by me or someone else, the user have to remember that the output and input are not the same, and cannot forget to modify the predictions by `pred += 1`.

Comment: This answer looks good to me - the first (unused) output unit will always have a probability of 0. Taking the argmax of the predictions will yield the desired class.